# How to set custom price for products on the basis of quantity in shopify?

Tags: shopify, product, price

Greetings.

I am working on a eCommerce website based on shopify. And for product I want to set a custom price. For example, The standard price of product is $500 but price will vary if user increased the quantity i.e. On 5 - 10 it will cost $450, On 11 - 15 it will cost $400 and on 20+ quantity it will cost $300.

I have searched module for this and also found a module i.e. https://apps.shopify.com/quantity-breaks. But its working on the basis of "Percent" that I don't need. Because I want to place price manually on the basis of quantity.

So please help me out from this and provide your valuable thoughts on the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this is generally done in Shopify is to create variants where the option values are the price breaks. You have to modify your theme so that when a Qty > price break is entered the product page selects the variant that corresponds to that price level.

Other than the coding portion of this the main issue becomes inventory management since Shopify treats each variant as a separate inventory item but if you use variants to manage price breaks they are not actually separate items.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be with a Shopify App. There are many that have price breaks etc. and they are usually easier to set up than using variants as the price break amounts.

Comment: Hi Mennyg.
Can you please suggest few apps for this ?

Note : Percentage basis price not need. Need to add price manually for products based on quantity.

Comment: There is one by Bold and a few others. Search the App Store for "Quantity Breaks"